# Why does std::reverse require bidirectional iterators?

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, reverse, iterator-traits

Why does `std::reverse(c.begin(), c.end())` require that the underlying container `c` provides *bidirectional iterator*?

De-facto this would mean (multi-)`map`, (multi-)`set`, but those can not reversed, of course, because they are ordered. The only other *bi-dir* container is `list` but that one has its own member function `.reverse()`.

This means that one can apply `std::reverse` on `array`, `vector` and `deque` which are *random-access*.

So, why not be "honest" and say: random-access is required, or use the member function?

Comment: Because that'd be unnecessarily restrictive against user-defined iterators

Comment: @krzaq I thought as much. But I thought it is strange to not being able to apply a specified function to 80% of the shipped potential targets. I probably would have invented a iterator-category in between, or orthogonal, say "ordered" or something. Esp. because the non-applicability is not mentioned in the doc for `std::reverse` on those ref-pages. Maybe in the spec itself?

Comment: Can I use a `map` or `set` as a `merge`-target (output iterator required)? How about `remove` on `map` and or `set`? Probably not, because they reorder, but where is that written?

Comment: @krzaq You could write that as an answer.

Comment: "*So, why not be "honest" and say: random-access is required*" Because random access is not required, so that would be dishonest.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to go user-defined iterators, you provide an answer in your own question.

> The only other *bi-dir* container is `list` but that one has its own member function `.reverse()`.

That member function, however, reverses the whole list. `std::reverse` allows only part of the list to be reversed, by passing other iterators than `list.begin()` and `list.end()`.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this would be unnecessarily restrictive for user-defined iterators or cointainers using bidireactional iterators. And since random access is not necessary, it shouldn't be required.

Comment: Or user defined containers using bidirectional iterators.